# Development using my production DB server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi for some reason after I setup my app for deployment, I also added the link to the remote DB I have, and after that even though I'm in development it connects to my production database.

No clue why. Here's the database.yml file:

```
development:
 <<: *default
 database: mk_development

production:
 <<: *default
 url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>

default: &default
 adapter: postgresql
 encoding: unicode
 # For details on connection pooling, see rails configuration guide
 # http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
 pool: 5
```

Comment: Please show your `default` settings in this file

Comment: Are you sure you have setup your environment? Did you set `RAILS_ENV` environment variable (http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-environment-settings)?

Comment: I ran 

rails_env=development rails s  and 
bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development 

for some reason it seems to think I'm in production?

Comment: is there a DATABASE_URL environment variable set?

Comment: @FrederickCheung yes there are as you can see on the production, I also have it stored locally

Comment: I don't mean is it used in your file but is it set in your development environment (ie does `echo $DATABASE_URL` output anything)

Comment: yeah. As I said I have it set locally (as in my development environment)